# Не работают манипуляторы вывода потока вместе с std::setiosflags

Tags: c++, io

Не работает такой простейший вывод:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
   int x(84568);
   std::cout << std::setiosflags( std::ios_base::hex | std::ios_base::showbase | std::ios_base::uppercase) << x << std::endl;
   std::cout << x << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Вывод таков:

```
84568 

84568
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Не работает" в данном случае именно `std::ios_base::hex`.

Функция `setiosflags` выставляет флаги по логике побитового ИЛИ. `std::ios_base::hex` - это не просто один флаг, который можно просто взять и выставить. Форматам `dec`, `hex` и `oct` по понятным причинам соответствует целое битовое поле, состоящее из нескольких битов. Выставлять значение этого поля по логике ИЛИ (как это делает `setiosflags`) будет неправильно. Единичные биты для `hex`, разумеется, выставятся, но уже уже присутствовавшие в этом поле единичные биты, скажем, для `dec` при этом не сбросятся. В результате произойдет "перемешивание" битов `dec` и битов `hex` с непредсказуемым результатом. В вашем случае формат просто остался `dec`.

Для того, чтобы перейти в формат `hex` через `setiosflags` надо сначала обнулить быты, ответственные за выбор системы счисления, а уж затем можно будет применять побитовое ИЛИ для выставления нового значения флагов через `setiosflags`. Например

```
std::cout <<
  std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::basefield) << 
  std::setiosflags(std::ios_base::hex) << 
  x << std::endl;
```

Когда вы пользуетесь манипулятором `std::hex` он все делает за вас сам - чистит старые флаги и выставляет новые. А если вы хотите пользоваться `setiosflags` - то чистка флагов становится вашей ответственностью.